# Query about template style of site being used in php

Tags: php

One of my client sent zip file today, which contains website source code, he is developing.

When i opened "template" folder and "template-comments.html" file.

I saw some "variable" being used there with `%` arround it.

One of line is :-

```
<title>%title%</title>
```

Whole template folder is filled with such files. I am just not sure, how it has been done. Yes, I know you might be thinking, what a lame programmer i am. I am working for client, and i am just not sure, what his file mean.

I am good(not best) in PHP. I have developed custom e-commerce webapplication using phpfastcache and all. But, I have never experienced such coding style in my life.

I beg my pardon for my lame question, but i am seriously not aware of such coding style and i am eager to know.

**Most Important: Whole website doesnot use any PHP framework.**

Can anyone help me understand such coding style.

If i am unclear on any part. Kindly ask, But i am desperate to learn this.

**Note: These are not placeholder, but these style is being used in running website. Here is image link, I have removed few info just to keep privacy.**
[image: POC]

Thanks

**Update: I got the answer. 
Person is first using `file_get_contents` from `something.php` for getting info from file "something.html" and than using `str_replace` function to replace the actual link with `placeholder`.**

Thanks

Comment: That is not a “coding style” in itself, but just a means of marking placeholders, that then afterwards get replaced by some kind of template engine or similar.

Comment: Placeholder waiting for the bigger picture...

Comment: No, he has running website with those template. Nothing Changed. I have his `FTP` details, and i have verified those things in his website too.

Comment: here is link of image. I have erased few info to just keep privacy of work. http://i.imgur.com/bxseBT7.png Thanks

Comment: As luck would have it `%` isn't all that common in php scripts, so grepping for it might give you an answer.

Comment: I will do grepping, but what text should i use for my `grep`. Thanks

Comment: `grep -r  '%' .` and look for results which implies parsing, like explode, preg_match and so on...

Comment: I got the answer. Person is first using `file_get_contents` from something.php for getting info from file "something.html" and than using `str_replace` function to replace the actual link with placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Template Engines that replace those placeholder for values that you specified, the syntax of the placeholder can vary depending on the Template Engine. As example take a look at [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.basic.syntax.tpl#language.syntax.comments) and its syntax.

```
<title>{title}</title>
```

Conclusion, he maybe using a Template Engine.